# Naming array dimensions gives error: length of 'dimnames' not equal to array extent

Tags: arrays, r, dimensions, names

This is my first time using a 3 dimensional array and I am having problems about naming the third dimension.

```
ReplicateData <- array(0, c(240, 500, 5), dimnames=list(NULL, NULL, c("Returns", "Replicates", "Asset Class")))
```

I am getting the error:

> Length of dimnames not equal to array extent

This seems like it should be a simple issue but I can't find an explicit example in the help docs or online.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The third dimension of your array is of extent 5, but the vector of names for that dimension is of length three.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that the name length should match the number of dimensions.

Comment: Well, that's something you can have, too;
something we call "named dimnames".
The table() function actually is an important example using them:  
  
> with(airquality, table(OzHi=Ozone > 80, Month, useNA="ifany"))
    
           Month
    OzHi     5  6  7  8  9
      FALSE 25  9 20 19 27
      TRUE   1  0  6  7  2
      <NA>   5 21  5  5  1
  
You'd manually use something like  
    tab. <- array(1:15, dim=c(3,5), dimnames=
        list(OzHi = c("FALSE", "TRUE", NA),
             Month = c("5", "6", "7", "8", "9")))

to get the "same"  [why on earth, can't I get "markdown" to work?]

Answer (score 8):

Since I understand answers better with a bit 'o code to guide me... here is Jonathan Chang's correct answer translated to code:

```
ReplicateData <- array(0,c(240,500,5),dimnames=list(NULL, NULL, 
  c("Returns","Replicates","Asset Class", "Fourth Dimname", "Fifth Dimname")))
```